# Trying to create a SQL VIEW with multiple criteria in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm wondering if it is strait forward enough to create a view in the following way, my attempts are not working as expected,

**I'm trying to create another view with the following query that identifies the offending 'grp' when the following condition is true:**

original description of my thoughts regarding condition:

SELECT grp FROM control WHERE

('control_1.pvalue' || ' (2nd)' !=  'control_2.pvalue')

OR

('control_1.pvalue' || ' (3rd)' !=  'control_3.pvalue')

OR

('control_1.pvalue' || ' (4th)' !=  'control_4.pvalue')

OR

('control_1.pvalue' || ' (5th)' !=  'control_5.pvalue')

OR

('control_1.pvalue' || ' (6th)' !=  'control_6.pvalue')

---

I tried the following expecting to have **M2** returned:

`SELECT grp FROM control_1 WHERE (pvalue || " (2nd)" != (SELECT pvalue from control_2) AND grp = (SELECT grp from control_2));`

But even this basic step is not working for me.

---

Run the code snippet below to see the table and views that I'm trying to attempt this on.

```css
th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div>
<div>CREATE TABLE control (</div>
<div>id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,</div>
<div>grp TEXT,</div>
<div>pname TEXT,</div>
<div>pvalue TEXT);</div>
<div></div><br />

<table>
<tr><td colspan="4"><div>control</div></td></tr>
<tr><th>id</th><th>grp</th><th>pname</th><th>pvalue</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>M1</td><td>d1</td><td>vat</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>M1</td><td>d2</td><td>vat (2nd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>M1</td><td>d3</td><td>vat (3rd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>M1</td><td>d4</td><td>vat (4th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>M1</td><td>d5</td><td>vat (5th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>M1</td><td>d6</td><td>vat (6th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>M2</td><td>d1</td><td>bin</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>M2</td><td>d2</td><td>ban (2nd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>M2</td><td>d3</td><td>bin (3rd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>M2</td><td>d4</td><td>bin (4th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>M2</td><td>d5</td><td>bin (5th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td><td>M2</td><td>d6</td><td>bin (6th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>M3</td><td>d1</td><td>haw</td></tr>
<tr><td>14</td><td>M3</td><td>d2</td><td>haw (2nd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>15</td><td>M3</td><td>d3</td><td>ha (3rd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>16</td><td>M3</td><td>d4</td><td>haw (4th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>17</td><td>M3</td><td>d5</td><td>haw (5th)</td></tr>
<tr><td>18</td><td>M3</td><td>d6</td><td>haw (6th)</td></tr>
</table>
<div></div><br />
<div>CREATE VIEW control_1 AS SELECT * FROM control WHERE pname = "d1";</div>
<div></div>

<table>
<tr><th colspan="4">control_1</th></tr>
<tr><th>id</th><th>grp</th><th>pname</th><th>pvalue</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>M1</td><td>d1</td><td>vat</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>M2</td><td>d1</td><td>bin</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>M3</td><td>d1</td><td>haw</td></tr>
</table>
<div></div><br />
<div></div>
<div>CREATE VIEW control_1 AS SELECT * FROM control WHERE pname = "d2";</div>
<div></div>

<table>
<tr><th colspan="4">control_2</th></tr>
<tr><th>id</th><th>grp</th><th>pname</th><th>pvalue</th></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>M1</td><td>d2</td><td>vat (2nd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>M2</td><td>d2</td><td>ban (2nd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>14</td><td>M3</td><td>d2</td><td>haw (2nd)</td></tr>
</table>
<div></div><br />
<div>
<div>CREATE VIEW control_1 AS SELECT * FROM control WHERE pname = "d3";</div>
<div></div>

<table>
<tr><th colspan="4">control_3</th></tr>
<tr><th>id</th><th>grp</th><th>pname</th><th>pvalue</th></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>M1</td><td>d3</td><td>vat (3rd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>M2</td><td>d3</td><td>bin (3rd)</td></tr>
<tr><td>15</td><td>M3</td><td>d3</td><td>ha (3rd)</td></tr>
</table>
<div></div><br />

<div>
<div>--I create the following as well, but we can see the problems from the 1st three views</div>
<div>CREATE VIEW control_1 AS SELECT * FROM control WHERE pname = "d4";</div>
<div>CREATE VIEW control_1 AS SELECT * FROM control WHERE pname = "d5";</div>
<div>CREATE VIEW control_1 AS SELECT * FROM control WHERE pname = "d6";</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an epiphany, and I was able to figure out the following:

I have created two new views as follows, and I'm now getting what I am expecting.

```
create view dview as
SELECT
DISTINCT
grp,
(select pvalue from control_1 WHERE control.grp == grp) as d1,
(select pvalue from control_2 WHERE control.grp == grp) as d2,
(select pvalue from control_3 WHERE control.grp == grp) as d3,
(select pvalue from control_4 WHERE control.grp == grp) as d4,
(select pvalue from control_5 WHERE control.grp == grp) as d5,
(select pvalue from control_6 WHERE control.grp == grp) as d6
FROM control;
```

Here's the select statement on this new view:

```
select * from dview;
grp         d1          d2          d3          d4          d5          d6
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
M1          vat         vat (2nd)   vat (3rd)   vat (4th)   vat (5th)   vat (6th)
M2          bin         ban (2nd)   bin (3rd)   bin (4th)   bin (5th)   bin (6th)
M3          haw         haw (2nd)   ha (3rd)    haw (4th)   haw (5th)   haw (6th)
```

Begin new view creation:

```
create view dview_err as
SELECT * FROM dview WHERE
(d1 || " (2nd)" != d2) OR
(d1 || " (3rd)" != d3) OR
(d1 || " (4th)" != d4) OR
(d1 || " (5th)" != d5) OR
(d1 || " (6th)" != d6);
```

Here's the select statement on this new view:

```
select grp from dview_err;
grp
----------
M2
M3
```